# Objects registered in HTTPContext scope still reported by the Model.InstancesOf method

Tags: structuremap

When initializing my aspx page, I declare it (inside OnInit) in the StructureMap container to get it injected into the appropriate presenter:

```
container.Configure(x => x.For<IMyInterface>().HttpContextScoped().Use(this));
```

HttpContextScope should force removing "this" (i.e. the page object) from the container at the end of the current request. To prove it I've added - just after the above line - the following code:

```
IEnumerable<InstanceRef> refs = container.Model.InstancesOf<IMyInterface>();
foreach (InstanceRef r in refs)
{
  Type t = r.ConcreteType;
}
```

The question is:

Why the refs collection increases by 1 in each postback?

It not only increases but r.ConcreteType doesn't raise any exception - it means that the underlying object really exist. The page is injected into the presenter which is itself declared in the HttpContext scope.

What am I doing wrong that HttpContext scope seems to work incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

---

I've thought it over and the result is as follows. If I configured the container to **create** a new instance of my class (it (configuration) would be done only once, during Application_Start), the container would create an instance and then - really delete it at the end of the Http request. But I only **register** the existing instance of this class. The container is not the instance's owner and therefore it may not delete it - but the configuration keeps the reference to it (therefore it can't be deleted at all). At the other side, the configuration item is not removed by anybody, anytime (but added in every Http request).

Therefore all that works as it works. It is, of course, my misunderstanding of "HttpContextScoped" (and some other things :-( ).

So, I'm at the starting point: is there any way to remove such a registration from the configuration?

[Edited]
It seems that I can't remove such a registration. The solution is: replace the automatic constructor injection with a manual property injection. I.e.: create the presenter (without its view) and then - set the view manually: thePresenter.View = this;
The aforementioned registration is not added and the problem just doeasn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
container.Configure(x => x.For<IMyInterface>().HttpContextScoped().Use(this));
```

is misleading. It makes you think that you're registering it as `HttpContextScoped` but in reality it's registered as singleton.

You could use a lambda to "create" the object:

```
container.Configure(x => x.For<IMyInterface>().HttpContextScoped().Use(c => this));
```

The lambda method is used to create the object, but normal scoping rules should still apply. In fact, if you use a factory, you might not even need the scoping rules at all (since the lambda is evaluated lazily).

Comment: I've replaced "this" with "c => this" but it seems not to help. The refs collection is still increasing.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense. The value of `this` never changes, so you're continually adding references to it.